# Query Json and pass variable?

Tags: jquery, json

I am pulling data with `$.getJSON` and displaying it in a div. I thought I would have another json query to get one product but I don't so I was wondering of there is anyway to query the results or just grab a few variables to pass?  I need to pass one record to another page.  I found this on this site:

```
var people = json.filter(function(el)
{          
   return el.Phoneno.some(function(number)
   {
       return number.Cell == "777-777-7777";     
   });
});
```

Seems like I need to pull the entire query again though and parse through it. Is there away to just pass a few variables to another page?  Very new to jQuery, if someone could point me it right direction that would be great, thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

```
$.getJSON("myurl", function(data){
   $.each(data.myproducts, function(i,item){
      $("#products").append("<li><a href='"+item.Url+"' target='_top'><img src='"+item.image+"'></a>"
                           +"<br>"+item.Name+"<br>"+"$"+item.saleprice+"</li>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to pull the entire query again? Could you provide a bit more code?

Comment: What do you need to see?  The json?

Comment: $.getJSON("http://myurl",   
function(data){        
  $.each(data.myproducts, function(i,item){          
  $("#products").append("<li><a href='"+item.Url+"' target='_top'><img src='"+item.image+"'></a>"+"<br>"+item.Name+"<br>"+"$"+item.saleprice+"</li>");         
     
 });      
});

Comment: this brings back everything fine but now I need one product from this passed to another page

Comment: Right, that's the part I'm wondering about. What do you mean by "passed to another page?"

Comment: So you can see it brings everything back, I am getting all the results, I have them in a carousel and he wants to be able to link to a new page from the carousel, that diplays one product. So this is the only query I have.  I need to pull info for one product and pass it to the new page.

Comment: "Pass it to the new page" how? Through the link?

Comment: That is what I was thinking...make a new page with json query I have and pass an id? Or just pass the variables I need from this page?  Is any of this possible with JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a JavaScript object:

```
var data = {
    url: 'http://example.com',
    image: 'http://placekitten.com/200/300',
    name: 'can haz cheezburger?'
};
```

through a URL query parameter by serializing it to JSON:

```
var strData = JSON.stringify(data);
// '{"url":"http://example.com","image":"http://placekitten.com/200/300","name":"can haz cheezburger?"}'
```

and then URL-encoding it:

```
var encodedStrData = encodeURIComponent(strData);
// '%7B%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%22%2C%22image%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fplacekitten.com%2F200%2F300%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22can%20haz%20cheezburger%3F%22%7D'
```

and then adding it to the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) of a URL. If you have an anchor like this:

```
<a id="next" href="next/page">Next Page</a>
```

you can modify it with jQuery like this:

```
var $next = $('#next'),
    url = $next.prop('href') + '?data=' + encodedStrData;

$next.prop('href', url);
```

The receiving page will then have to unpack the data in the URL, if present.

---

...or you could just pass some sort of item ID:

```
<a href="next/page?item=42">Next Page</a>
```

---

#### Edit

Try this, which uses [`$.param(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param) instead of `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(...))`:

```
$.getJSON("myurl", function(data)
{
    $.each(data.myproducts, function(i,item)
    {
        var url = 'details.html?' + $.param({data: item});
       
        $("#products").append("<li><a href='"+url+"' target='_top'><img src='"+item.image+"'></a>"
               +"<br>"+item.Name+"<br>"+"$"+item.saleprice+"</li>");
    });
});
```

<sub>This can definitely be cleaned up, but I've left it as similar to the original code as possible for clarity. [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is a great resource for improving correct code.</sub>

Then, on the receiving page, you need to grab the value of the `data` parameter. I recommend using [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) for that:

```
$(function ()
{
    var item = $.deparam.querystring().data;
    // Item is now one of the items from the JSON on the previous page.
    // Do whatever you need with it
});
```

Comment: Wow OK, thanks. What is the best way?  If I pass the id then I need to find the data on the next page so your first example seems like the way to go.  Is there a tutorial somewhere?  This is new to me and I am a little lost. I don't even know where / how to set the data to pass.

Comment: Is the link that you're talking about the one that you create in the `$.each()`?

Comment: Right now I am pulling a link from the json - they don't want that now, they want a new page to display one prodcut and that will link to the url I am using now.  Make sense?

Comment: If there is a way to pass the id and then pull one product from the json I am using now, it seems like that would be the simpliest way to go.

Comment: So if I pass the id - is there a way to use json.filter to grab one record on another page?

Comment: I really don't want to grab the data twice though, do I?

Comment: You can either grab the data twice, once on each page, or you can pass the entire (encoded) object in the URL. Those are your options. I know next to nothing about the system you're building, so it's your choice and not mine.

Comment: Thanks for your help Matt. they changed this today and want it now. I think passing the object is probably the best way, best to avoid grabbing the data twice I think.  So do you know of a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: No, I'm not much of a tutorial user. I've laid out the basic steps. Do you not understand how it fits together?

Comment: Okay. Which link do you need to modify? Is it the one that's generated in the `$.each()` function?

Comment: Yes.  I am going to make a new page called details.html and change href='"+item.productUrl+"' to href='details.html'

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help. That worked and I can see it in the url but I can't get it on to the new page.  I was just trying to print it out and can't get it to work. Is there something I need to do to it first?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Did you remember to add jQuery **and** the BBQ plugin script to the new page?

Comment: $.deparam. is null or not an object

Comment: I am on the BBQ pages tring to figure it out! Argh

Comment: What I meant is, you need something like `<script src="path/to/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have that but I can't see how to extract the data that gets passed.  It should be on the BBQ link you posted somewhere so I am looking for it.

Comment: Same error in the console (`$.deparam. is null or not an object`)? If so, the BBQ plugin isn't loading. Make sure that the `<script>` tag for the plugin comes _after_ the `<script>` tag for jQuery.

Comment: That is gone now - no errors - but still can't get the data on the new page,  have been all over the BBQ site and I am still lost as to how to do it.

Comment: I lied - it's not gone, it's only in ie though

Comment: @mark too many comments. Bring it to [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) or make a new question